# How to use a type defined and associated with a Template parameter in a class Template?

Tags: c++, templates

Below is an implementation of the above question.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

class Data {
    int val;
};

template<class T>
class Test {
public:
    Test(){};
private:
    typename T::container  _data;
};

class FunTest:public Test<FunTest> {
public:
    typedef std::map<uint16_t, FunTest > container;
    FunTest():Test(){}
};


int main()
{
    FunTest object;
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
}
```

I tried the above but I get the error

```
Error   C2039   'container': is not a member of 'FunTest'   Temp
```

Any insight on why this gives an error is much appreciated.

Comment: `Test<FunTest>` will instantiate the template specialization before `container` is declared, so `T::container` cannot use it. This could usually be resolved by moving `container` in an external traits template. However, `std::map` cannot be used recursively. You cannot have a `std::map` member with the class itself as value type.

Comment: @user17732522 this explanatuon makes a lot of sense. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

According to user17732522

> Test will instantiate the template specialization before
> container is declared, so T::container cannot use it.

So I guess one solution could be to move the typedef to `Test` class as a protected variable.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

template<class T>
class Test {
public:
    Test() {};

protected:
    typedef std::map<uint16_t, T> container;

private:
    typename container  _data;
};

class FunTest :public Test<FunTest> {
public:
    
    FunTest() :Test() {}
    //Test<FunTest>::container c; access here as well if needed
};


int main()
{
    FunTest object;
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
}
```